# R matplot() function: how to keep the indices on the x-axis but only plot specific values from the matrix

Tags: r, plot

So let's say you have a vector

```
a = c(1:10)
```

But I only want to plot element 2,5 and 7, but at indices 2, 5 7. Not: y values 2,5 and 7 at x values 1,2,3

I can use:

```
plot(a[c(2,5,7)],a[c(2,5,7)])

plot_subset_ind
```

However, for the function `matplot()`, when plotting a matrix, I don't know how to do this:

original:

```
matplot(t(max_invest_year_zero_matrix/1000))
```

not-working because all data is shifted one index:

```
matplot(t(max_invest_year_zero_matrix[,plot_subset_ind]/1000))
```

Maybe I should replace the non-plotted values with NaN values.

Comment: It's not clear if you want to plot some columns or just some rows of all columns.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear if you want to plot some columns or just some rows of all columns.
See the difference between the two plots below. And note that `t()` isn't used by neither.

```
max_invest_year_zero_matrix <- matrix(1:64, ncol = 8)

plot_subset_ind <- c(2, 5, 7)
matplot(max_invest_year_zero_matrix[plot_subset_ind, ])
matplot(max_invest_year_zero_matrix[, plot_subset_ind])
```